# Problem with iPhone URL Schemes for launching app and Mobile Safari - I'm getting stuck in a loop!

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios4

Need some help with iPhone development here....

I made a custom URL scheme for my app. It allows other apps, as well as Mobile Safari, to launch my app. It looks somewhat like this:

myapp://

This will launch "myapp". If I type that into Mobile Safari, my app launches.

I've created a website that, in the end, redirects to myapp:// and launches the app. The problem is that now every time I open Mobile Safari manually, my app automatically gets launched. It's stuck. I have to kill the windows quickly in Mobile Safari, or kill Safari in the task manager, in order for this looping to stop.

Does anyone have a solution to this? Even if I do the following:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.newurl.com/"]];
```

It opened Mobile Safari, and then opens the URL I want to go to, but for some reason if my redirect page is still open somewhere in the background it just relaunches my app again.

Thanks.

Comment: How does your site redirect to `myapp://`?

Answer (score 0):

The issue, I think, is that mobile safari is trying to load myapp:// whenever the browser itself is opened (because it is trying to load the corresponding tab). A solution might be to programmatically close the browsing tab once you have been redirected your app- that way the page does not stay in mobile safari, redirecting you every time you open the browser.

Comment: How do I programmatically close the tab? Is that even possible?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it is, try this [link](http://blogs.x2line.com/al/articles/350.aspx)